# using a list from subprocess output

Tags: python-3.x, fail2ban

I use subprocess and python3 in the following script:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("fail2ban-client -d".split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
out.decode('ascii')
print(out)
```

The output is the following:

```
['set', 'syslogsocket', 'auto']
['set', 'loglevel', 'INFO']
['set', 'logtarget', '/var/log/fail2ban.log']
['set', 'dbfile', '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3']
['set', 'dbpurgeage', 86400]
...
```

My issue is all this output is not a list. This is just a really big string with new line.
I have tried to convert each line to a list with this command:

```
eval(out.decode('ascii').split('\n')[0])
```

But I don't think this is the good way.
So my question is how can I convert a string (which looks like a list) to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though people generally are afraid of using `eval`, it *is* the way to go if you need to convert text literals into data. Instead of splitting up your (potentially long) string, you can simply read off the first line like so:

```
import io
f = io.StringIO(out.decode('ascii'))
first_list = eval(f.readline())
second_list = eval(f.readline())
```

Comment: Why use `eval` when you've got `ast.literal_eval` though?

Comment: Ah, very nice. Yes, replace `eval` with `ast.literal_eval` for safer code. And don't forget to import `ast` first.